# populate edit record screen from table A if record found, else table b

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Want to add an "edit" function to an asp.net C# application so that a certain role of users can create an edited version of a record submitted by a "standard" user. The original record is retained in table A, and the edited version is stored in table B (with a reference to the original record). What I want to be able to add to this however is if the editor clicks on the edit button for a record they have already edited to be able to ask them (via popup?) if they want to create a new edited record, or create a new edited record and load the page based on this answer.

Currently a user clicks on the Edit Question linkbutton on a gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' runat="server" CommandName="editQuestion">Edit Question</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

That launches an Edit Question page via rowcommand statement:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "viewQuestion")
        {
            Session["PageIndex"] = GridView1.PageIndex;
            Session["QuestionId"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("~/Review/ReviewDetail.aspx?Id=" + Convert.ToString(Session["QuestionId"]));
        }
        if(e.CommandName == "editQuestion")
        {
            Session["PageIndex"] = GridView1.PageIndex;
            Session["QuestionId"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("~/Review/EditQuestion.aspx?Id=" + Convert.ToString(Session["QuestionId"]));
        }
    }
```

Which loads the page with a stored procedure that pulls up the applicable record from table A:

```
using (Conn)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_CloneSElect", Conn);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QuestionID", SqlDbType.BigInt));
                command.Parameters["@QuestionID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Id"]);
                Conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    txt_ImageID.Text = reader["ImageID"].ToString();
                    txt_Date.Text = reader["SubmitDate"].ToString();
                    txt_Stem.Text = reader["Stem"].ToString();
                    txt_RespA.Text = reader["RespA"].ToString();
                    txt_RespB.Text = reader["RespB"].ToString();
                    txt_RespC.Text = reader["RespC"].ToString();
                    txt_RespD.Text = reader["RespD"].ToString();
                    txt_RespE.Text = reader["RespE"].ToString();
                    DDResponse.SelectedValue = reader["Answer"].ToString();
                    txt_Critique.Text = reader["Critique"].ToString();
                    txt_KeyObjective.Text = reader["KeyObjective"].ToString();
                    txt_References.Text = reader["References"].ToString();
                    DDPractice1.SelectedValue = reader["PracticeArea1"].ToString();
                    DDPractice2.SelectedValue = reader["PracticeArea2"].ToString();
                    DDPractice3.SelectedValue = reader["PracticeArea3"].ToString();
                    DDPractice4.SelectedValue = reader["PracticeArea4"].ToString();
                    txt_QuestionID.Text = reader["Id"].ToString();
                    txt_IsCloneOf.Text = reader["IsCloneOf"].ToString();
                }
                reader.Close();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (Conn)
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT QuestionID, Images2.ImageID, ImageFile, ImageContent, ImageName, SEQ_NUM from qimages join Images2 on qimages.imageid = images2.imageid where QuestionID = @QuestionID", Conn);
                    ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("QuestionID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = txt_QuestionID.Text;
                    ad.Fill(dt);
                }
                dlImages.DataSource = dt;
                dlImages.DataBind();
            }
```

I could figure out how to have the underlying stored procedure do the logic to pull from table b if exists, else table a,,, but don't know how to ask the user the question and add the new variable to the inputs on the stored procedure, or if it would be easier to change the stored procedure called based on user answer to the question "You have already edited this question, do you want to view this record or create new edited version?"

Comment: OT, but important: When you say `using (Conn)`, do you understand that `Conn` will be disposed, but not set to `null`, at the end of the `using` block? This is why the convention with `using` is to declare the reference *within* the `using` block parens (e.g. `using (var foo = new Foo()) {`), and also why you never see a `using (foo)` nested within `using (foo)`. You don't need or want to dispose `Conn` twice, and you certainly don't want it to be in scope outside of the `using` block which disposes it.

Comment: To make it simple, don't do this in the **SP**. Instead make another query to check if there is any value exists for `TableA`. If not, then go to `TableB`. Even you can use `IF` statement in the **SP**.

Comment: @AT-2016 - What I don't know how to do is create the popup message asking if you want to create new or "re-edit" existing edit and then pass a value based on that response. New to Asp.net and C#

Comment: See this for pop up window - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-Multiple-Buttons-to-jQuery-UI-Dialog-Modal-Popup.aspx